# breakpoints in hosted IronPython scripts

Tags: ironpython

I know I can set breakpoints and debug stand-alone IronPython scripts in VisualStudio.  However, I have an application which hosts the IronPython engine.  If I want to debug a script running in the hosted engine, is there a way to set breakpoints and step through the script?  Should I be methods other than ExecuteFile to accomplish this?  Basically I would like to attach the debugger to the process, break at ExecuteFile, and then step through the IronPython code.

```csharp
// engine is the hosted IronPython engine and script is the .py file to execute
engine.ExecuteFile(script);
```

EDIT: I believe this is a dupe of [Debugging IronPython scripts in hosted (embedded) environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676188/debugging-ironpython-scripts-in-hosted-embedded-environment).  Wasn't able to find this one before posting my question.  Go ahead and close this one.