# How to register a managed debugger in VS Integrated Shell

Tags: c#, ironpython, managed, ironpython-studio, mdbg

My team currently has a fork of the Iron Python Integrated Shell project where we completely implemented our own custom language using managed C#. Our current implementation does not utilize any debug engine (it uses some hacky alternative) and my task is to figure out if it's possible to replace what we have by registering a custom, managed debug engine with the shell.

After a lot of research, I did stumble upon this project: [CLR Managed Debugger (mdbg) Sample 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282) but I do not understand how one would register such an engine with the integrated shell.

If anyone has an idea or resource to point me in the right direction, that would be most appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161718.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've been to that page before, and it's all C++/ATL. I am specifically looking at my options for running a managed debugger, which they regrettably don't cover.

Comment: The integration with VS is COM-based, the language does not matter.  [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493557/writing-an-iron-python-debugger) for hints.