# Iron python debugger for my application

Tags: wpf, ironpython, avalonedit

I have a WPF application.It has a iron python script editor using AvalonEdit. We were able to validate and run the iron python scripts using this application.
But we need to integrate an iron python debugger in to this application.

Can anyone suggest better solution for this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493557/writing-an-iron-python-debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `pdb` and `dbd`. This are some very useful modules. You could go through the code and integrate it in your application.

Comment: We have implemented it using visual studio isolated shell

Comment: Do you have used PTVS or your complete own solution? If it's your complete own solution, you might share some information with us :)

Comment: Instead of embedding the debugger into our application, we have started VS Shell as a different process and attached the python script to VS shell from our application

Comment: And the VS shell is extended with your own plugin or PTVS?

Comment: In VS 2013 shell, PTVS is integrated into it http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneOfMicrosoftsBestKeptSecretsPythonToolsForVisualStudioPTVS.aspx