# Debug IronPython in hosted/embedded C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ironpython, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing asp.net core application + IronPython.
But I've faced with the debugging issue...

So for example I have following code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Debug"] = true;
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);

// output redirect
var eIO = engine.Runtime.IO;

var errors = new MemoryStream();
eIO.SetErrorOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);

var result = new MemoryStream();
eIO.SetOutput(result, Encoding.Default);

// execute script
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("testGlobalVar", 10);
engine.ExecuteFile(ScriptPath, scope);
```

in python file

```py
some = "Test"

print(Test)
print("We have ->", testGlobalVar)
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to set breakpoint in python file and debug it step by step in Visual Studio, Pycharm(whatever), when running it via C#.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676188/debugging-ironpython-scripts-in-hosted-embedded-environment) but it's almost completely useless. I'm setting breakpoint in python file and nothing happens.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: After you set breakpoint on it, and choose Start Debugging(F5), anything happens? Please check your python environments in Solution Explorer to make sure the environment is OK.

Comment: Breakpoints works only for C# code, for python it says "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document".

@LanceLi-MSFT can you send screenshots how everything must be configured?
This is what i have https://monosnap.com/file/JarPr2hOfdTXqP7oPUoMdjXyAVPRmf

Comment: Do you start debugging under debug mode? And what the result if you create a new IronPython project, add breakpoint and debug it? can it succeed?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT yes, i do it in debug mode. If  i creating new IronPython without .net core projects, it works ok. But in embedded style not.

Comment: Not sure about the cause but I guess this issue may have something to do with the way you load the .py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works well without debug mode as you mentioned. I think the reason for why the breakpoint won't be hit in debug mode is debugger can't find it.

Please `Go=>Debug=>Options`=>Uncheck `Enable Just My Code` to check if it helps.

Note:

1. Set the .net core app as startup project
2. If the uncheck `Enable Just My Code` not help, I suggest you go `tools->Import/Export Settings->reset all settings`, then uncheck the `Enable Just My Code` again.

After that, the breakpoint can be hit like below:

[image]

In addition: I use the .net console app to reproduce and test, but I think it has similar behavior like web-app. Any update feel free to contact me :)

Comment: Glad to know my answer helps :) Have a nice day!